# Get Excel columns in list (Python or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, excel, list

I am trying to get a list/array of the columns of an Excel spreadsheet, from A until ZZ.

```
["A","B","C", ... , "ZX","ZY","ZZ"]
```

What I have tried so far:

(Javascript)

```
const alphabetList = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('');
const alphabetListCopy = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('');

for (var i=0; i < alphabetListCopy.length; i++){
  for (var j=0; i < alphabetListCopy.length; j++){
    alphabetList.push(alphabetList[i][j]);
  }
}

console.log(alphabetList);
```

and this returns `Error: Invalid array length`

(I did the loop with alphabetListCopy to avoid this error [https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/push-new-element-into-array-using-for-loop/225401#:~:text=Your%20code%20crashed,push%20an%20element.](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/push-new-element-into-array-using-for-loop/225401#:%7E:text=Your%20code%20crashed,push%20an%20element.))

In python I tried:

```
alphabet = "A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z".split("-")

for letter in alphabet:
    for a in alphabet:
        alphabet.append(letter + a)
        
print(alphabet)
```

and this returns a MemoryError (I assumed it created an infinite loop)

Comment: In both JS and Python you're adding items to the array you iterate over, thus making an essentially endless loop that forever grows an array in memory. Until you get an error about it.

Comment: @James no, it's just `undefined` (mostly) because `alphabetList[i]` resolves to a string and `[j]` will access a non-existing character from it (for any `j > 1`).

Comment: @VLAZ right, yes it won't throw an error, the values will be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are providing is making an infinite loop because you are appending values to an array and you are trying to add a value to a 2-dimension array while `alphabetList` is a 1-dimansion.

If you want to have a list of the values from A to ZZ in Javascript you can do this instead :

```js
const alphabetList = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('');

// here we do not want to make it const since we are populating it
let alphabetListCopy = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('');
for(i = 0; i < alphabetList.length; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < alphabetList.length; j++) {
        alphabetListCopy.push(`${alphabetList[i]}${alphabetList[j]}`) // we add to the array the new value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import string
alphabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

new= []
for alpha in alphabet:
    for a in range(len(alphabet)):
        new.append(alpha+alphabet[a])
    
len(alphabet+new)
```

The same code in single line (ternary format):

```
alphabet+[alphabet[a]+alpha for a in range(len(alphabet)) for alpha in alphabet]
```

New list length `702`

Answer (score 0):

For an easy approach to get the alphabet:

```
alphabet = [chr(i) for i in range(65, 91)]
```

To get all combinations, itertools has a nice collection of tools:

```
import itertools
alpha_combi = [''.join(subset) for subset in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=2)]
alphabet += alpha_combi
```

where each `subset` is a tuple of two letters.

Comment: Thank you, there's only 1 problem with this code, when you get to "B", the first combination is BB, not BA, C the first one is CC, and the first combination of Z is ZZ.

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely right. For your application, ```itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=2)``` is needed. I will update the answer.